# How would you say, "How beautiful!"

Tags: idiom, word-request

I am eating a hot dog in a beautiful courtyard right around dusk, and I would like to exclaim in Latin, "How beautiful!"

I thought of saying "Quam pulchra!" which can't be far off, but I am wondering whether there is a better choice. For example, would *miranda* be better? Would any other words be better?

I look forward to your feedback, so that on similar twilit evenings I can exclaim this without hesitation.

Comment: I'd use *o* + accusative of exclamation: *o pulchrum!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the superlative of any appropriate adjective: *iucundissima, suavissima, , dulcissima* or, especially in those circumstances, *amoenissima*. It gives more of the emphasis that you seem to be looking for. You might avoid the ellipse with *Tempestas, quam amoenissima!* or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth *quam pulchra* is attested in a Post-Classical context (Vulgate:)

> Quam pulchra es et quam decora, carissima, in deliciis! [(Can 7, 7)](http://www.vatican.va/archive/bible/nova_vulgata/documents/nova-vulgata_vt_canticum-canticorum_lt.html#7)

Perseus treats *quam* as too common a word (a *stop word*, excluded from searches,) so it is difficult to look for the whole phrase. I found by chance an example of *tam pulchra* that is attested classically:

> quid ais, Eruci? tot praedia, tam pulchra, tam fructuosa ([Cic. S. Rosc. 15](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0010:text=S.%20Rosc.:chapter=15&highlight=quam%20pulchra%2C), 43)

... and also examples of quam + *adverb* (unfortunately no adjectives so far) as an exclamation. Prominently:

> quam multa quam paucis! (*how much [you have said] in a few [words]*, from a [letter by Cicero to D. Brutus](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:UKJhX-xJVpQJ:https://www.loebclassics.com/view/marcus_tullius_cicero-letters_friends/2001/pb_LCL230.349.xml%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk))

Comment: _Quam_ + adj. is quite normal. _Vale quam optime!_ is an accepted way of saying an informal good-bye.

Comment: @TomCotton sure, what I was looking for is verbless or copulative exclamations

Comment: [Fronto](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/1248/3/4/3001-3013@1#4) also uses *quam pulchra*.